# Extract text from pdf not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdftotext

I am trying to extract some text from a PDF file in Laravel using Spatie-PdfToText. However, I get the error no such file or directory. The function is in this path `app\Http\Controllers\AddRecordsController` and the PDF in this path `\app\Http\Controllers\book.pdf`.

I've also tried changing the path in `getText()` to the path written above but same error.

Code to extract:

```
    public function readPDF(){

        echo Pdf::getText('book.pdf'); //returns the text
    }
```

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: you should provide the full path to pdf where it has directory write permission

Comment: Hi @kish77
Did you find the solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in first you need instal binary library.
if you use Ubuntu or Debian:

```
apt-get install poppler-utils
```

or if use RedHat or CentOS:

```
yum install poppler-utils
```

After it install library via composer:

```
composer require spatie/pdf-to-text
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;
...
echo Pdf::getText('/path/to/file.pdf');
```

Comment: The answer is irrelevant to the question.